# Не отображается xml файл

Tags: android, kotlin

Проблема: при переходе на другое активити оно не отображается, просто черный экран НО код выполняется(проверял с помощью point-ов)

Откуда перехожу:

```
override fun onListItemClick(l: ListView?, v: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id)
    if (position == 0){
        val i = Intent(this, SearchGameTest::class.java)
        startActivity(i)
    }
}
```

xml этого файла:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/fon">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_marginTop="250sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

xml файла НА который перехожу:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SearchGameTest"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/QuestionField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        style="@style/MainText">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AnswerField1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        style = "@style/MainText">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AnswerField2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        style="@style/MainText">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AnswerField3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        style="@style/MainText">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ButtonNext"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="70sp"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:layout_marginStart="300sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="italic">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Код активити на которую перехожу.

```
class SearchGameTest : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.search_game_test)
        val q = ArrayList<String>()
            q.add("2 + 2")
                q.add("5 + 5")
        val a = ArrayList<String>()
            a.add("4")
                a.add("5")
                    a.add("6")
                        a.add("10")
                            a.add("11")
                                a.add("12")
        val c = MainClass(ButtonNext, QuestionField, AnswerField1, AnswerField2, AnswerField3, q, a)
            c.start()
                c.next()
    }
```

}

Comment: В приведённом коде ошибок не видно. Разве что у вас размеры через `sp` заданы, что неправильно, ибо надо `dp` использовать, т.к. `sp` - только для размеров текста следует использовать. Попробуйте заменить вашу разметку на любую другую. Может в ней что-то не так. И/или покажите код второй активити.

Comment: Увы... Не помогло.

Comment: Если вы будете оставлять подробные комментарии - вам будет проще помочь. Например вы не сказали что именно попробовали. Заменить sp на sp или другую разметку подставить. Также вы проигнорировали последнее предложение из моего первого коммента - не показали код второй активити.

Comment: Я поменял sp на dp. Сейчас приложу код

Comment: Каких-то явных проблем в коде не видно. Кроме `sp` вместо `dp` - это точно надо поменять вне зависимости от того, является ли это причиной проблемы. Сама же причина, возможно, в коде, который у вас в открываемой активити идёт после `setContentView()`. Попробуйте его закоментировать, возможно это поможет. И соблюдайте конвенции именования - аргументы MainClass с 99% вероятностью должны быть с маленькой буквы. Пока они с большой - код выглядит очень подозрительно.

Comment: Итак, закоментировал все что после setContentView() код стал работать. Также поменял названия аргументов на маленькую букву проблему это не решило.

Comment: Все. Проблема найдена. Дело в функции next() буду смотреть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Каких-то явных проблем в коде не видно. Кроме sp вместо dp - это точно надо поменять вне зависимости от того, является ли это причиной проблемы. Сама же причина, возможно, в коде, который у вас в открываемой активити идёт после setContentView(). Попробуйте его закоментировать, возможно это поможет. И соблюдайте конвенции именования - аргументы MainClass с 99% вероятностью должны быть с маленькой буквы. Пока они с большой - код выглядит очень подозрительно.